# I'm getting this error in Fedora 24 and don't know what to do

Tags: linux, fedora, bind

`systemd` status:

```
named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-10-08 21:40:00 EDT; 21min ago
  Process: 3918 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z /etc/named.conf; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled";

Oct 08 21:40:00 F24server.nspdom1.local systemd[1]: Starting Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)...
Oct 08 21:40:00 F24server.nspdom1.local bash[3918]: /etc/named.conf:11: missing ';' before '}'
Oct 08 21:40:00 F24server.nspdom1.local systemd[1]: named.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 08 21:40:00 F24server.nspdom1.local systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Oct 08 21:40:00 F24server.nspdom1.local systemd[1]: named.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 08 21:40:00 F24server.nspdom1.local systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

`named.conf` file:

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 192.168.100.10; 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { 192.168.100.0/24; localhost; };
```

Comment: Is that your entire `named.conf` file?

Comment: There seems to be at least a `}` missing from the `named.conf` file, at the end. The error message also seems to refer to a line 11, which does not exist in the `named.conf` that you have shown. Consider double-checking the file and update the question with the correct data.

Comment: @Ali Raza : There have been a number of edits by stack-exchange people. I am sure that the resulting `named.conf` file is not the file on your system (it is now 8 lines and the error messages is on line 11).  Can you please re-edit your question and put your named.conf in place of the edited versions?

Comment: @LjmDullaart Just for reference: As a moderator, I can see the exact formatting of the text in comments, and my edit with regards to the `named.conf` file in the question was due to peeking at the formatting in a now-deleted comment from the OP.

Comment: "I'm getting this error in Fedora 24 and don't know what to do" make configuration file syntatically correct or dont use bind if you dont understand it's configuration
  https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_18_7/reference.html#options-block-grammar

Comment: Fedora 24 has long been unsupported and packages from it contain known remotely exploitable vulnerabilities.